# Implement a generic type to pass around

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am sure this is duplicate but I am not sure I am searching for the correct answers. Or understanding that it answers my question.
For 1 I think I am using my interface wrong. For 1 I break the rules of SOLID and am trying to clean it up.  For example `IReelWindow`.  I have things in there specific to `ReelWindowTumble` that the other `ReelWindows` don't use and throw not implemented errors.  I started breaking it up into multiple interfaces but found i no longer had access to functions for `ReelWindowTumble`, even though I created a new interface for `ITumble` and still inherited from `IReelWindow`.  The problem is in the functional code.

```
public interface IReelWindow 
{
    //stuff declared
    void PopulateWindowTumble();
    void PopulateWindow(int[] currentStops);
}
public class ReelWindow : IReelWindow
{
// implements most of it  throwing exceptions when I don't use it.  
    public void PopulateWindow(int[] currentStops)
    {
    }
    public void PopulateWindowTumble()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class ReelWindowTumble : IReelWindow
{
// implements most of it  throwing exceptions when I don't use it.  
    public void PopulateWindow(int[] currentStops)
    {
    }
    void PopulateWindowTumble()
    {

    }
}
public class ReelWindowIndependent : IReelWindow
{
// implements most of it  throwing exceptions when I don't use it.
    public void PopulateWindow(int[] currentStops)
    {
    }  
    public void PopulateWindowTumble()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here I declare a new `IReelWindow` and create a new `ReelWindow` based on client input.  This works ok, as I just pass `IReelWindow` everywhere I want to use a ReelWindow.
I don't think this is the proper usage of my interface.  If I use `ICloneable`, i don't declare a new object of `ICloneable` and pass it around.
But my intention is to create a Generic `ReelWindow` Type.  I don't care what type of window the client creates.  I just want to enforce what functions it should have as I use them specifically.
How do I declare a Generic `ReelWindow` that I can pass around without creating multiple functions that are identical but have strong types passed in?

```
public static IReelWindow CreateReelWindow(WindowType userSelectedWindowType, Paytable paytable)
{
    IReelWindow _reelWindow;
    if (userSelectedWindowType == WindowType.Standard)
    {
        _reelWindow = new ReelWindow(paytable.ColLengths, paytable.ReelContainer.Reels, paytable.WindowWidth,                     paytable.Lineset, paytable.ReelContainer.TotalPhysicalReelStop);
    }
    else if (userSelectedWindowType == WindowType.Tumble)
    {
        _reelWindow = new ReelWindowTumble(paytable.ColLengths, paytable.ReelContainer.Reels, paytable.WindowWidth, paytable.Lineset, paytable.ReelContainer.TotalPhysicalReelStop);
    }
    else if (userSelectedWindowType == WindowType.Independent)
    {
        _reelWindow = new ReelWindowIndependent(paytable.ColLengths, paytable.ReelContainer.Reels, paytable.WindowWidth, paytable.Lineset, paytable.ReelContainer.TotalPhysicalReelStop, paytable.ReelLengths, paytable.ReelStarts);
        }
        else
            throw new ApplicationException("Unknown window type selected by user. Cannot continue.");
        return _reelWindow;
    }
```

Later in my code I use the reelwindows, and only pass in 'IReelWindow' as I don't care what type of reelwindow, the function will use it accordingly.

```
public abstract class AEval
{
    public abstract double Evaluate(IReelWindow reelWindow, ref string flags, int currentStopsWeight);
    public abstract double EvaluateVerbose(IReelWindow reelWindow, ref string flags, int currentStopsWeight);
}
```

Comment: You're right that throwing NIE from interface implementations is a code smell, but without more detail of the interface, and its usage its hard to answer your question meaningfully.

Answer (score 0):

The object that you are passing around is _reelWindow and while it implements IReelWindow, it is not an IReelWindow object. Instead it is one of your derived types: ReelWindow, ReelWindowTumble, ReelWindowIndependent, etc. Each of those derived types should be treated the same by your client (as you noted).

Let's pretend ReelWindow implements 2 methods from the interface, ReelWindowTumble implements 3 methods from the interface, and ReelWindowIndependent implements 10 methods from the interface. And the interface has a maximum of 10 methods to implement.

Using the language of your example, that means that ReelWindow will have 8 methods with NotImplementedException (NIE), ReelWindowTumble will have 7 methods NIE, and ReelWindowIndependent has 0 methods NIE.

What about your client code? Well, for all of this to make sense your client code should be calling all 10 of the interface methods while working with _reelWindow. That also means, using my example, that ReelWindowIndependent should work just fine with the client code because it has no NIE methods.

I'd say that your real problem is the NIE's. Remove those exceptions and instead return null. Then, in your client code, during flow of control, you can add statements to the effect of "if returned object is null, skip this section".

Remember, all objects inherit from 'object'. Those strongly typed return objects in your interface can be returned as 'object' too. That means any strongly typed object can be set to null. To repeat: try returning null value for methods with strongly typed return values and handling the null in your client code. Now, if the interface method has no return - it is marked void - then you don't need to worry about checking for null in your client code, nor would you need NIE: the method can be left blank and when called literally does nothing. If you ponder this, you might strive for interface design that does not use strongly typed return values. And that goes to Jamiec's comment: we need to know more about the interface.

Comment: So I am using my interface correctly? And I just need to handle the NIE's differently?  Seems like the same smell just handled better than crashing the program.

Comment: Nope, it isn't the same smell. Just imagine an interface called IDriveCar. And you have two cars: AutomaticCar and StandardCar. Both of them will implement IDriveCar. Let's pretend they both implement method titled ShiftGears(); but the automatic car will "do nothing" with its implementation method of ShiftGears() .... after all its an automatic car.  The StandardCar will implement it with "use hand to move gear shift lever to next gear" and the AutomaticCar will implement it with "do nothing" - what it won't do is throw an NIE and crash the car!

Comment: OK.  I get that piece.  But when you declare a new car (auto or standard) are you declaring new IDriveCar?   Or are you declaring new AutomaticCar which was forced to implement ShiftGears() because of I drive car.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "declare". You can only use the 'new' keyword on the derived type: AutomaticCar or StandardCar. You cannot use 'new' keyword on an interface. At least, that is how I am interpreting your usage of the word 'declare' - that you are making a new object from a class. Both of the derived types implement the interface.